# AngularJS & Bootstrap - Replacing a Menu

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

In an Angular+Bootstrap app, I need to have a menu (fixed to the bottom, BTW) with some items.
One of the items is supposed to replace the menu itself once clicked.

Think of:

```
---------------------------------------------
|   Option1 |   Option2 |   Select Number   |
---------------------------------------------
```

When the right menu item is clicked, the menu itself is replaced with something like this:

```
---------------------------------
|   <-  |   1   |   2   |   3   |
---------------------------------
```

Here, clicking the left arrow brings back the previous menu while clicking a number leads to a different flow.

My question: is having a boolean variable on the $scope and using ng-show & ng-hide the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use ng-repeat to create the menu items and custom filter. it is more elegant.